# Facebook fan page: Is there a way to get description of a Facebook fan page using Graph API

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to work on the description of some pages. I am using Graph API to get the page object. I dont find the description of the page in the page object.

Is there a way to fetch the description, plot outline of a facebook fan page using Graph API?

Language: Java
Library used: RestFB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Graph API you can get only the name, category and the number of users who like a page. No description.

If you want to get more info about that page you have available the `page` table. Using this you can get not only the info available through API, but many others including picture, type, website, company overview, mission, products etc.

In order to query this table you have to use FQL, and a query might look like this:

```
SELECT pic, type, website, company_overview, mission, products, location FROM page WHERE page_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID
```

Documentation for this table is available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) and how to execute FQL queries using your library is available on the page you provided at the end of your question.

Good luck !

Comment: i found a solution for the problem. i made a change is restFB to give description field also. thanks for your answers. really appreciate that :)

Comment: I'm glad you get it working. if the answer was helpful you know what you have to do :)

Answer (score 0):

please provide here some code then only we can know what problem you have, check your acess_token.

`

```
"data": [

       ],
       "paging": {
          "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/fan_page_id/insights?access_token=****&since=...",
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/fan_page_id/insights?access_token=****&since=..."
       }
    `
```

Comment: I am able to get the page from facebook. But the API does not give me the description of the page. I am able to get fan count, page title and other information except the description of the fan page.

Answer (score 0):

I used restFB to connect to Facebook Graph API. You can download it @ http://restfb.com/

In com.restfb.types.Page source file, add the following line:

```
@Facebook("description")
private String description;
```

Also write a getter for description

```
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

Compile the library and you can fetch the description automatically each time you fire a query.